# What is the type of the component returned from withStyles()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-component, jss

I have a `Dictionary` component with very simple properties:

```
interface DictionaryProps {
  word: string;
}
```

In the props of another component I request a generic component which only needs a string word:

```
dictionary: React.ComponentClass<{ word: string }>;
```

Its parent uses it like this:

```
<UsesDictionary dictionary={Dictionary} />
```

---

Now I want to experiment with JSS (MaterialUI is already used across the project, so no, a whole library is *not* used for just a single component). I created some styles and updated the `DictionaryProps` accordingly:

```
const styles = createStyles({ root: { position: 'relative' } });

interface DictionaryProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles>{
  word: string;
}

class Dictionary extends React.Component<DictionaryProps> {}

export default withStyles(styles)(Dictionary);
```

Which produces the following compile error when passing the styled `Dictionary` to the `React.ComponentClass`-accepting `UsesDictionary`:

```
Types of property 'dictionary' are incompatible.
  Type 'ComponentType<Overwrite<DictionaryProps, StyledComponentProps<"root">>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ word: string; }> & ComponentClass<{ word: string; }>'.
    Type 'StatelessComponent<Overwrite<DictionaryProps, StyledComponentProps<"root">>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ word: string; }> & ComponentClass<{ word: string; }>'.
      Type 'StatelessComponent<Overwrite<DictionaryProps, StyledComponentProps<"root">>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ word: string; }>'.
```

I confirmed that `Dictionary` matches `React.ComponentClass<{ word: string }>` by using it directly:

```
<Dictionary word={dictionarySearch} />
```

This shows I haven't somehow messed up the properties of `Dictionary`.

---

1. I can use `any` instead of a concrete type, but I've set a rule for this project not to use `any`. Anyway it's a bad practice as it looses type-safety.
2. I tried directly using the type from the error - `StatelessComponent<Overwrite<DictionaryProps, StyledComponentProps<"root">>>`. *But*:

   - It has some `Overwrite` type which I'm unaware of, and didn't find where it resides. I guess it's from MaterialUI, and I don't want to link `UsesDictionary` to it.
   - It needs the **styled** `DictionaryProps`, not just the `{word: string}` part, . And I don't want to couple my `UsesDictionary` to any concrete dictionary type, so I don't want it to know whether the dictionary uses `withStyles` or not.

   I.e. using the type from the error is not a viable option.

Others with `withStyles` problems use it as decorator, hence their errors. Here this doesn't apply as I'm alredy using `withStyles` as a plain function.

---

In short:

## How should I type the `dictionary` property of `UsesDictionary` so that it accepts a `withStyles`-ed component?

Answer (score 0):

*I deleted my question initially because when posting I had a silly mistake causing an error with the solution bellow, which I had tried even before asking. I think this might be helpful to others so I decided to undelete the question and post the solution as an answer.*

A working solution is to **union** the current type *with its functional component counterpart*.

```
readonly dictionary:
  | React.ComponentClass<{ word: string }>
  | React.StatelessComponent<{ word: string }>;
```

I got the idea to try this while looking at the error message. I noted it was trying to assign a `StatelessComponent` to my ComponentClass.